# querying posts with a custom status

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to query some wordpress posts, they have a custom post status of `closed`.

When I run this query, they get returned despite their custom status being set to `closed`, even though I've asked for `published`:

```
$now = strtotime(date('d.m.Y H:i:s'));
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'vacancy',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-closing-date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-closing-date',
            'value' => $now,
            'compare' => '<=',
        )
    ),
);
$vacancies = new WP_Query($args);
```

I would have expected that only posts with the `post_status` of `published` would have come back.  Anybody any ideas why this is returning `closed` posts?

Comment: The correct post_status for a published post is "publish" not "published". https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: Cool! I've posted it as an answer so you can close this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct [`post_status`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters) for a 'published' post is 'publish':

```
'post_status' => 'publish',
```

Comment: Good catch Michelle !

Answer (score -1):

The post_status `closed` is not part of the default post_status.

This custom post status is maybe add by a plugin or theme.

If you find `register_post_status` in your files, there are custom post status, and maybe an array to convert `closed` to `pending` or something else.

if not look for `add_meta_boxes` action.

You can also try to var_dump a closed post custom fields to see if it is not add to à custom meta field.
If it's the case, you will get your publish posts by excluding them with `meta_query` parameter.

Hope it gives some hints!